# Advanced Search Functionality - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

i'm working on an advanced search functionality on my website.
Basically data I'm working on is stored within two tables.

First table contains basic information about the product (1 row = 1 product so it's unique).
Table structure may look like this:

```
id, title, description
```

The second table contains more information about the product. The product may but don't have to have any rows here. However, one product may store in the second table a few rows. What's more - data in the second table should be used to the advanced search functionality. Table structure may looks like this:

```
id, item_id (from table 1), value_id (from another table), value
```

I want to select only these products (table 1) which has specified value_id (from column 2):

```
... WHERE table1.item_id = 5 AND table2.value_id = 1000
```

As I mentioned before - table 2 may but doesn't have to contains any rows connected by item_id with the table 1.

I've tried to use JOIN/LEFT JOIN function in SQL but in this case when the product has 3 rows in the table 2 - a query result returns 3 rows instead of 1 or 0 (if not found any results).

How can I handle that?

Comment: It would help if you showed some sample data and expected results. You say you get an item multifold, so it seems an item can have multiple rows for one value_id. As you want to see each item only once in your result, it seems you don't want to select the values. But, as you see, we must make assumptioms, as your request lacks this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to select products. So select from the product table. You want to select only those for which exists a certain attribute. So create an approriate `WHERE` clause. As you want to look up data in another table, you could use `EXISTS` or `IN`.

```
select *
from items
where id in (select item_id from item_values where value_id = 1000);
```